# How to speed up jdbc sql query which fetches image and text

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, swingworker

I am fetching image and text from database ,the image type is *longblob* when i include image in my SQL Query it takes a lot of time to display results , I don't know what's wrong , but when i remove photo in my SQL query results take less than one second . connection is ok and works well, problem is the speed, please help me ?

External Connection class :

```
     public class jconnect_registry {

public static Connection connectDb2() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn2 = 
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registry", "root", "root");
        return conn2;
    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection problem ");

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Main class whereI use to call connection to tatabase :

```
 // connect to database 
   Connection conn2 = jconnect_registry.connectDb2();

   // Fetch data(text and image) from mysql 


     private void FindStudentInfo() {
   String sql7;
    Image image;
     Image newImg ;
     ImageIcon ic;
     byte[] imagedata ;
        try{
         sql7 = "select Registration_No,Names,Faculty,Department,photo as 'profile' from students where Registration_No = '" + this.srchregno_txtfld.getText() + "'";
         ps25 = conn2.prepareStatement(sql7);
         rs25 = ps25.executeQuery();

        //set image to image jlabel
        if(rs25.next()) {

                String add1 = rs25.getString("Registration_No");
                this.Regno_jlabel.setText(add1);
                String add2 = rs25.getString("Names");
                this.FirstName_jlabel.setText(add2);
                String add3 = rs25.getString("Faculty");
                this.fclty_jlabel.setText(add3);
                String add4 = rs25.getString("Department");
                this.dpt_jlabel.setText(add4);                  
                 imagedata = rs25.getBytes("profile");
                 ic = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
                 image = ic.getImage();
                 newImg = image.getScaledInstance(this.img_jlabel1.getWidth(), this.img_jlabel1.getHeight(), 40);     
                 ic = new ImageIcon(newImg);
                 this.img_jlabel1.setIcon(ic);

        }}
```

Comment: Store also the scaled image. In general you could leave all photos as files in the file system: `fileName = add1 + "_profile.jpg";`.

Comment: @Joop Eggen  I can understand you, but just imagine if you are working on existing data where you need to this issue however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and ever answer I got is to use primary key as index in where clause.
The where clause defines the search condition of an SQL statement, and it thus falls into the core functional domain of an index: finding data quickly. Although the where clause has a huge impact on performance, it is often phrased carelessly so that the database has to scan a large part of the index. The result: a poorly written where clause is the first ingredient of a slow query.

Therefore my code no can fetch Image in microseconds because I reformulate an sql query as follows :

```
    sql7 = "select Registration_No,Names,Faculty,Department,photo as 'profile' from students where Id ='"+jLabelId.getText()+"'  and Registration_No = '" + this.srchregno_txtfld.getText() + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do two queries. The first one, with the "fast" data, like Strings, numbers, etc. Then, a second query with the "slow" data, the image, will be done in a separate thread.

The user will see a dialog with all the data and a reserved space for an image that will appear a litte bit later. You can put a little progress animation or something like that.

It's more or less the same thing you see when you navigate in internet...

Answer (score 0):

Well, first let me say, that storing (big) images in a relational database makes no sense and you should not do it. Anyway it seems like you are dealing with an existing system and you can not change it.

The problem you have, is that image data is quite big in comparison to all the other data. So if you add the this image to your query, it is clear that the query will be much slower, as the data has to be gathered and sent via the network. You only have one where clause, so there is not much to optimize here. The only thing you can do is, to setup an index on the column Registration_No or reduce the size of your query.

Comment: thinking , Thanks for good and clear idea , but I don't get this logic show me an example using my code how I can setup an index on the column Registration_No or reduce the size of my query,'cause even if i  only call profile , doesn't work

Comment: You can setup indexes on your database, depending on the database you use e.g. [MariaDB index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-index/).

If your image is to big, consider saving the image to the file system or use the way Nil was proposing.